# PHP cms submit in textarea not working

Tags: php, content-management-system, textarea, submit

i got a problem with my simple cms in php.
I can get website content in an textarea and after i edited it i want to send the new edited content to the database, but thats not working.
here is my form and functions

editContent.php

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title> Basic CMS - Admin Area</title>
    <h1>Admin Area Edit Content</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    include ('includes/functions.php');

    $cont = getContent();

    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    ?>
    <span>Logged In! Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?></span>
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    <a href="editContent.php">Wijzig content</a>
    <a href="index.php">Admin Home</a>

    <form action="doEditcontent.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="contentarea"><?php echo $cont['content'];?></textarea><br>
    Submit : <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>

<?php
} else {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

functions.php

```
<?php
include('includes/connect.php');

function getContent(){
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT content FROM taalcontent WHERE taalid = 1 AND contentid = 1") or die (mysql_error());
    return mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    echo $query;
}

function editContent($pContent) {
    if(isset($pContent)){
        $query = "UPDATE taalcontent SET content content = '$pContent'  WHERE contendid = 1 AND taalid = 1";
    } else {
        echo "fout";
    }
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

doEditcontent.php

```
<?php
include('includes/functions.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['contentarea'])){       
        editContent($_POST['contentarea']);
        header("Location: ../index.php?page=2");   
    } else 
        echo "Please enter some content!";
} else {
    header("Location: ../index.php?page=1");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
editContent($_GET['content']);
```

to

```
 editContent($_POST['contentarea']);
```

As it is you are asking it to set the content to whatever is in the `?get` parameter (which I can't see referenced anywhere else so I'm guessing its not populated with anything).

:)

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the wrong argument when you call the function editContent($pContent). Also, you should define the function before it's referenced.
Try this way:

```
    <form action="doEditcontent.php" method="post">
    <textarea name="contentarea"><?php echo $cont['content'];?></textarea><br>
    Submit : <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>

    <?php
    include('includes/functions.php');


    function editContent($pContent) {
if(isset($pContent)){
    $query = "UPDATE taalcontent SET content content = '$pContent'  WHERE contendid = 1 AND taalid = 1";
} else {
    echo "fout";
}
mysql_query($query);
    }


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if(isset($_POST['contentarea'])){       
    editContent($_POST['contentarea']);
    header("Location: ../index.php?page=2");   
} else 
    echo "Please enter some content!";
    } else {
header("Location: ../index.php?page=1");
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: those are just pieces of code i got from different files. i included them at top of the pages

Comment: I defined the function editContent before you called it and, as Dom suggested, put $_POST['contentarea'] instead of $_GET['content'].

Comment: i posted all my files now, maybe that is more clear to you now